# Different Way for assigning value to a variable in SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Can i write the following query in other way?

```
ALTER PROC Proc_AssetManagement_SubscriptionCheck @IMEINumber NVARCHAR(100)
,@PhoneNo NVARCHAR(200)
,@SIMNo NVARCHAR(100)
,@Id INT
,@Message NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @SimMessage NVARCHAR(200) = ''
DECLARE @PhoneMessage NVARCHAR(200) = ''
SET @Message = ''

SELECT @Message = (
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(IMEINumber) > 0
                THEN ('IMEI Already Exists\n')
            ELSE ' '
            END
        )
FROM tblAssetSubscriptionDetails
WHERE AssetMgmtId <> @Id
    AND (IMEINumber = @IMEINumber)

SELECT @PhoneMessage = (
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(PhoneNo) > 0
                THEN ('PhoneNo Already Exists\n')
            ELSE ' '
            END
        )
FROM tblAssetSubscriptionDetails
WHERE AssetMgmtId <> @Id
    AND (PhoneNo = @PhoneNo)

SELECT @SimMessage = (
        CASE 
            WHEN COUNT(SimNo) > 0
                THEN ('SimNo Already Exists')
            ELSE ' '
            END
        )
FROM tblAssetSubscriptionDetails
WHERE AssetMgmtId <> @Id
    AND (SIMNo = @SIMNo)

SET @Message = @Message + '' + @PhoneMessage + '' + @SimMessage
END
```

I want to reduce the number of queries and want to get the message in single query rather then 3 different queries. Can i do it? If so then how? 
My purpose is that I want to get a message formed like this.

If IMEINumber is found in the table then it will show IMEI number already exists.
If SIm No is found in the table along with IMEINumber then it will show IMEI number already exists\nSim No already exists and so on...

Comment: How are `IMEINumber`, `PhoneNo`and `SIMNo`related? Are they all related to one specific device or many?

Comment: Actually they are related to one specific device. And my question is not specific to IMEINumber, PhoneNo and SimNo. It can be any other columns. All i want is how can i get merged message in one single query So that i dont have to perform multiple queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this fit your need ? (Using a CTE: `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx`. I wrote it partially in Notepad++ so I hope there aren't syntax error.)

The CTE `tASD` (stands for `tblAssetSubscriptionDetails`) gathers only the rows that will be useful. `EXISTS` should normally be better than `Count() > 0` since it doesn't actually need to count everything.

```
WITH tASD(AssetMgmtId, IMEINumber, PhoneNo, SIMNo)
AS
(
    SELECT AssetMgmtId, IMEINumber, PhoneNo, SIMNo
    FROM tblAssetSubscriptionDetails
        WHERE AssetMgmtId <> @Id
            AND
            (
                IMEINumber = @IMEINumber
                OR PhoneNo = @PhoneNo
                OR SIMNo = @SIMNo
            )

)
SELECT @Message = (
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT null FROM tASD WHERE IMEINumber = @IMEINumber)
                THEN ('IMEI Already Exists\n')
            ELSE ''
            END
        )
        +
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT null FROM tASD WHERE PhoneNo = @PhoneNo)
                THEN ('PhoneNo Already Exists\n')
            ELSE ''
            END
        )
        +
        CASE 
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT null FROM tASD WHERE SIMNo = @SIMNo)
                THEN ('SimNo Already Exists')
            ELSE ''
            END
        )
```